# sklearn r2 score return very small value not close 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using mae, rmse, and r2 as evaluation metrics for regression problem.

Below are some of the actual values of the data I have and some of the predictions I got using the model.

```
actual = [3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3...SAME..., 3.3]  
predict = [3.274385532407407, 3.274385532407407, 3.274385532407407, 3.274385532407407, 3.274385532407407...SAME..., 3.274385532407407]
```

The difference between the actual and predicted values is very small. So I think the value of r2 should be close to 1, but the result of sklearn r2_score is -3.3268270525748175e+27 .

I checked the values in the list, but they all consist of the same value.

Why are these results and how should I understand them?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: All your true $y$ are the same (3.3) and so are the predicted $y$ (3.27..). What is behind this? Do you have any variation in $y$ at all?

Comment: I second the confusion about your constant $y$. // I don’t know how your software calculate $R^2$, but the way that makes sense to me is involves seeing by how much your predictions improve on predicting the mean value of $y$ every time. Since you get perfect predictions by predicting such a value every time, you can’t improve on that model, explaining why missing by only a little results in $R^2<0$. You might like what I [posted in response to a different Stack Exchange question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/563941/247274)